# PortAudio for MAC Mavericks

Tags: osx-mavericks, portaudio

Did anyone manage to build the latest stable version from `PortAudio` (v19 20140130) **on OS-X 10.9 - MAC Maverick**?
I am new both to `MAC` and to `PortAudio`, but did follow all instructions and received many errors during the build, some of them very basic (for example - file 'assert.h' was not found). My assumption is that MAC SDK version might be different from what `PortAudio` was expecting.
I am actually interested in the output binaries of the build - both x86 and x64, so if these could be downloaded from somewhere this also could be a solution.
Many thanks for any tip, PazO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem resolved**
***Background:***
In order to build `PortAudio` on MAC you need to run two commands: `configure` and `make`. This procedure is fully described [here](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_mac_coreaudio.html).
The first command - `configure` - suppose to build your *Makefile* file, enabling the next command - `make`- to work correctly.
One of the tasks of `configure` is to discover what *MacOS-SDK* version is installed on your system and what is the full path to it.
***The problem:***
The problem was that the `configure` script did not find the correct version of *MacOS-SDK* that is insalled on my Maverick system and thus made the next command - `make` - to fail.
***The fix:***
In the `configure.in` file there is a section that tries to discover what is the
version and location of the *MacOS SDK* that is installed on the local system.
Once discovered it will put the correct values into the local script variables 
`mac_version_min` and `mac_sysroot`.
Since this code was not working correctly I replaced it with the next two 'hard-coded'
lines:
`mac_version_min="-mmacosx-version-min=10.8"`
`mac_sysroot="-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk"`
After this all was building correctly.
PazO